# How to log B before A?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code

```js
function a() {
  b().then((success) => {
    if (success) {
      console.log('B')
    }
  })
}

function b() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true)
    console.log('A')
  })
}
a();
```

How to log `B` before `A` without using `setTimeout(()=>{console.log('A')}, 0)`

Comment: You can't, since you can't know if `b()` has succeed before it has logged `A`.

Comment: You cannot do that, see the way you are calling your function where they are meant to be called in and sync way since you are using `Promise`

Comment: Its not possible to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function as a value in the first Promise that will be executed later.

```js
function a() {
  b().then((success) => {
    if (success) {

      console.log('B')
      success()
    }
  })
}

function b() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(() => console.log('A'))

  })
}
a();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but here's what I came up with.

```
async function a() {
  await b().then((success) => {
    if (success) {
      console.log('B')
    }
  })
}

function b() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(true)
    console.log('A')
  })
}
```